# What does . match?

Tags: vim, sed, regular-expression, awk, perl

In working with regular expressions, I have been told that a dot character `.` will match *everything*.

Except for newlines `\n`.

Are there any other exceptions?  What about the NUL character `\0`, or the backspace character `\b`, or any of the other various non-printable ASCII characters?

Do different utility/programs like sed, awk, perl, and vim behave differently or the same in this aspect?

Comment: Depending on the utility, `.` is either anything, or anything except newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `info regex`:

```
3.2 The Match-any-character Operator (`.')
==========================================

This operator matches any single printing or nonprinting character
except it won't match a:

 newline
      if the syntax bit `RE_DOT_NEWLINE' isn't set.

 null
      if the syntax bit `RE_DOT_NOT_NULL' is set.
```

Comment: How come when I type `info regex` my manual isn't divided into chapters and sections?  This section doesn't even appear.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know - I just navigated down to *Common Operators* and pressed Enter on *"Match-any-character Operator::"*

Comment: :( I don't even have a Common Operators section.  Maybe it's because of LTS Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: @jw013 - Unfortunately, that documentation only says 
" '.' Matches any character, including newline."

Answer (score 1):

`.` is equivalent to `[^\n]` for all standard UNIX regex flavours, however, on Windows it is commonly `[^\r\n]` due to the syntax of Windows-style line endings. On other platforms, it should evaluate to whatever the standard newline sequence is.

In Perl and some other languages, single-line mode will make `.` also match `\n` (or `[\r\n]` on Windows regex flavours, etc), making it literally match anything.

Bear in mind the meaning of `.` may change depending on the context, for example, within POSIX bracket expressions the dot character matches a literal dot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any of the [Plan 9 utilities](http://swtch.com/plan9port/), perhaps the [Sam editor](http://sam.cat-v.org/), that use Structural [Regular Expressions](http://doc.cat-v.org/bell_labs/structural_regexps/se.pdf), the '.' meta-character matches every character *except* newline. I believe '@' matches any single character, including a newline.  The nature of [structural regular expressions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=665719) encourages writing multi-line patters, or maybe "patterns that ignore line-structure".  Looks like there's a structural regular expression [Python module](http://code.google.com/p/sregex/) in Google Code, but I can't google up much else in the way of implementations.